# Select distinct of selected rows

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm selecting rows from two tables

$a = mysql_query("SELECT a.id, a.id_user, a.id_location,  a.id_event, a.date
FROM    event as a
        LEFT JOIN rating as b
            ON a.id_event = b.id_event AND
                a.id_user = b.id_whos_get_rate
WHERE   a.id_user <> $log1[id] AND
        EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    event as c
            WHERE   a.id_event = c.id_event AND
                    c.id_user = $log1[id]
        ) AND
        b.id IS NULL ORDER BY DATA") ;

then I'm receiving array

a.id | a.id_user | a.id_location |  a.id_event | a.date
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  1        2           1               2         20.03.2013
  2        3           1               2         20.03.2013
  3        4           1               2         20.03.2013
  4        12          1               3         20.03.2013
  5        13          1               3         20.03.2013
  6        14          1               3         20.03.2013

Then I want to echo that values and adding radio by each user what I'm doing that way:

```
<pre>>while($b = mysql_fetch_array($a)){ 
>$place = mysql_query("select * from name_event where id=$b[id_location]");
>$place1= mysql_fetch_array($place);
>echo  $place1[name];
>echo $b[date].;
>echo "id event: ".$b[id_event].;
>$name= mysql_query("select* from users where id='".$b[id_user]."'and id!=$log1[id]");
>$name1= mysql_fetch_array($name);
>if (!empty($name1[login])){
>echo  $name1[login].   ;
>echo "form method ='post' action ='rate.php'
>rate
>input type='radio' name='s' value='$name1[id]|1|$b[id_event]' 
>input type='radio' name='s' value='$name1[id]|2|$b[id_event]' 
>input type='submit' name='submit' value='value'
```

the problem is that a.id_event has multiple values and I have no clue how to change the code to echo only once a.id_event and then all users which taking part in that event because at the moment it's echo

```
id_event 2 
id_user 2

id_event 2 
id_user 3

id_event 2 
id_user 4
```

and I'm expecting to work like that

```
id_event 2 
id_user 2
id_user 3
id_user 4
```

Comment: Please provide table schema and data and result you want. Keep it to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have your data ordered by the `id_event` and therefore the values are consecutive, I think the best answer to this would just to have a variable in your loop to contain last's id_event and just print the id_user if it's being repeated.

As an example:

```
$last_id_event = null;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($a)){ // Each row
    if($row['id_event'] != $last_id_event){
        echo "id event: ".$row['id_event'];
        $last_id_event = $row['id_event']
    }
    echo "id user: ".$row['id_user'];
}
```

EDIT: changed foreach to while(... mysql_fetch_array), which is the correct way to go.

Comment: shouldnt be some extra loop befor user echo id_user to echo them all for one event_id?

Comment: Not needed, as the loop is going for all the results and just not printing thos that have a repeated id_event. I'll edit the post reflecting that.

Comment: $last_id_event = null;
while($b = mysql_fetch_array($a)) {
// For each row.
foreach($b as $key => $row){

  if($b['id_event'] != $last_id_event){
echo  $b['id_event']."</br>";
$last_id_event = $b['id_event'];
  }
echo $b[id_user]."a"."</br>";
}} 
I've done like this, and I changed order by id_event and it works but it's multiplying values for one id_event it's echo 10 times same user_id 10 times the other user_id while in table it only one user_id for same event_id

Comment: I think that it works like that because of foreach condition choosing by $b ($a doesn't work at all) every selected row like date etc, that's why it's keep repeating

Comment: I'm not sure of why you're doing two loops: one with the while (which selects each row in the mysql array) and the foreach (which selects each column in the given row)

Comment: When I'm doing like that foreach($a as $key => $row){ then it shows error Invalid argument supplied for foreach() so I assumed I need to like $b = mysql_fetch_array($a);
$last_id_event = null;
foreach($b as $key => $row){
 if($row['id_event'] != $last_id_event){
  echo  $row['id_event']."</br>";
  $last_id_event = $row['id_event'];
  }
  echo $b[id_user]."</br>";
} and then come up 5
36
36
3
36
36
1
36
36
3
36
36
2
36
36 while only 36 is id_user and have no clue where from came the other digits because at the moment it should echo like that 3 36 4 36 32 (id_event 3,4 id_user 36, 32 )

Comment: $last_id_mecz = null;
$b = mysql_fetch_array($a);
foreach($b as  $row){
  if($b['id_event'] != $last_id_event){
  echo  $b['id_event']."</br>";
     $last_id_event = $b['id_event'];}
 echo $b[id_user]."a"."</br>";} i ve done like that and it select only one id_event and 10 times repeat id_user so it has to be  while loop before I think then it's repeating id_users as well but at least selecting all of id_event

Comment: You have me completly at loss. I'll see what I can do with what you're saying. You're right about the mysql_fetch_array, but I think only one loop is needed. Give me 5 minutes.